# exec function not working as expected

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I am running a shell function from php to convert a video file to flash once it is uploaded. The exec function is like this:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i " . WWW_ROOT . "files" . DS . "videos" . DS . $id . $ext . " -ar 22050 -r 32 -f flv -s 640x480 " . WWW_ROOT . "files" . DS . "videos" . DS . $id . ".flv");

// if I echo the string it returns:
// ffmpeg -i /home/vceroot/public_html/example.com/test/intraweb/app/webroot/files/videos/516c1203-0484-417a-b047-5488c40293e9.mpg -ar 22050 -r 32 -f flv -s 640x480 /home/vceroot/public_html/example.com/test/intraweb/app/webroot/files/videos/516c1203-0484-417a-b047-5488c40293e9.flv
// the locations are correct
```

However, it does not convert the video.

After it uploaded the file, it just goes back to the index action. There is no converted file although the uploaded file is there.

My permissions on the folder is 755. And the folder owner is apache. I don't know what else to do. Can anyone assist me?

**UPDATE**

So I've changed my exec query a bit and echoed the output:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i " . WWW_ROOT . "files" . DS . "videos" . DS . $id . $ext . " -ar 22050 -r 32 -f flv -s 640x480 " . WWW_ROOT . "files" . DS . "videos" . DS . $id . ".flv 2>&1", $output, $return);
die(print_r($output));
```

This returned the following error:

```
Array ( [0] => sh: ffmpeg: command not found ) 1
```

So I changed it a bit to this:

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i " . WWW_ROOT . "files" . DS . "videos" . DS . $id . $ext . " -ar 22050 -r 32 -f flv -s 640x480 " . WWW_ROOT . "files" . DS . "videos" . DS . $id . ".flv 2>&1", $output, $return);
die(print_r($output));
```

And now it returns:

```
Array ( [0] => /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavdevice.so.55: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory ) 1
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Have you checked the you have safe mode set to off in your php.ini file?

Comment: what is the exact `exec()` execution?

Comment: Also make sure you don't have `exec` in your disable_functions

Comment: Try putting your complete command in a var first, echo that, and check out your command including input params looks like expected.

Comment: @RenePot not sure what you mean. That is the line directly copied from my code.

Comment: @Pitchinnate how would I do that?

Comment: Check your php.ini file

Comment: Or use `phpinfo()` and make sure it isn't listed under `disable_functions`

Comment: Try locating 'ffmpeg' and see if it works if you run it with /path/to/bin/ffmpeg [arguments]. You can check out what the path is by running 'whereis ffmpeg'

Comment: @Pitchinnate nothing listed under disable_functions.

Comment: Are you running this from within apache, or on the command line? if it's command line, you're probably running as some user OTHER than the owner of the directory and therefore don't have write permissions.

Comment: @NiekvanderSteen updated the question. Your suggestion however does not work. I've added the path and still no luck. If I manually convert the video it works perfectly.

Comment: @MarcB how can I see which user it will run as? EDIT nevermind: A quick google showed ps aux | grep apache will do the trick. Two users are listed. root and nobody.

Comment: are you doing `$ php yourscript.php` at the prompt, or hitting `http://example.com/yourscript.php` via browser?

Comment: I'm running http://example.com/yourscript.php

Comment: @MarcB I've found out who is the user who runs the script when run through the browser.

Comment: @DarkRanger what does it execute after all variables are filled. So do `echo [exec code here, without the exec]`

Comment: @RenePot it is in my original question. Line 2 of the commented code. If I run that directly in the terminal, it converts with no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I googled my second error and fixed it by adding the location of `libavdevice.so.55` to the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file and running `ldconfig` after that.

It works now.